# How to extract specific data in R based on date?

Tags: r, date

I am new to R and do not have much experience. I have tried to get the answer on my own but as i am in a bit of a hurry i decided to ask here.

I have a bunch of stations with dailf flow data. I need to subset the data bsed on requred dates.

The data looks like this:

```
Date,Flow
11/3/1987,234
11/4/1987,430
11/5/1987,224
11/6/1987,233
11/7/1987,265
11/8/1987,978
11/9/1987,750
11/10/1987,467
11/11/1987,397
11/12/1987,465
11/13/1987,167
```

Lets say i need the subset with flow data between 11/7/1987 and 11/12/1987. Can you please advise how to proceed? I have tried with transforming the Table$Date with as.data but did not have success selecting the desired values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatting is an issue:

```
Table$Date = as.Date(Table$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

Use date objects to subset:

```
Table[Table$Date >= as.Date("1987-11-7") & Table$Date <= as.Date("1987-11-12"),]
```